# UIimageview drawInRect with aspect to fit mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

previously i had custom tableviewcell and was loading from Nib.in that i have specified mode "Aspect to fit" for my imageview. but loading this Nib file was too slow. so i have started drawing content of uitablewviewcell. here is a code for what i am doing to draw image.

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(10,10,80,100)];
```

but this does not give me same effect what i had in my Nib file. that is "Aspect to fit". image looks starched.so my question is how to achieve "Aspect to fit" mode using this code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image has the correct size (i.e., you don't need to scale it to fit into the drawing area), you can use

```
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
```

(or calculate the point differently if you want to center it).

Otherwise, you'll have to calculate a rect with the correct aspect ratio yourself.